# VueJS custom component

Tags: jquery, vue.js, crop

I need add to my component [jquery cropit plugin](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/). So I added cropit to my package.json and install

next I tried

```
<template>
  <div id="image-cropper">...</div>
</template>
```

and

```
import 'cropit'
export default{
  mounted: function(){
        $('#image-cropper').cropit({
            imageState: {
                src: 'http://lorempixel.com/500/400/',
            },
        });
  }
}
```

but is not working

chrome console output

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined at
>   Cropit.init (eval at  (app-d1eddf4073.js:2440),
>   :274:41)
>   at new Cropit (eval at  (app-d1eddf4073.js:2440),
>   :194:11)
>   at HTMLDivElement.eval (eval at  (app-d1eddf4073.js:2440),
>   :102:21)
>   at Function.each (eval at  (app-d1eddf4073.js:176),
>   :368:19)
>   at jQuery.fn.init.each (eval at  (app-d1eddf4073.js:176),
>   :157:17)
>   at jQuery.fn.init.init (eval at  (app-d1eddf4073.js:2440),
>   :96:18)
>   at jQuery.fn.init._jquery2.default.fn.cropit (eval at 
>   (app-d1eddf4073.js:2440), :147:26)
>   at VueComponent.mounted (eval at  (app-d1eddf4073.js:1565),
>   :65:29)
>   at callHook (eval at  (app-d1eddf4073.js:2428),
>   :2758:19)
>   at Object.insert (eval at  (app-d1eddf4073.js:2428),
>   :1769:5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `cropit` plugin isn't compatible with jQuery 3.0 and above versions at this moment. Check out this issue on [github](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/issues/197).

I installed `jQuery 2.1` and didn't found any errors in my console:

```
<template>
  <div class="cropit">
    <div id="image-cropper"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import cropit from "cropit"
import $ from "jquery"

export default {
  name: 'cropit',
  mounted: function() { 
    $('#image-cropper').cropit();
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what if everything else requires 3.0 ?

Comment: Cropit is jQuery plugin and it depends on jQuery. As you can see from github link other people have same issue like you - it isn't compatibile with jQuery 3.0

Comment: Try with lower version of jQuery, like I did, and you should not have any error.